# Which special characters is not allowed when add new picklist value?

Tags: picklist, global-picklist, character-encoding

When I attempted to add new picklist values, an error occurred that did not allow me to input the semicolon in the value. Do you have the full list of the special characters that are unallowed in the picklist value field? I tried to find the documents related to this problem but it doesn't seem to be available

`Error: Picklist values cannot contain a semicolon`
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, only `;` is diallowed; this is because, in SOQL, this character is used with INCLUDES and EXCLUDES to select values:

```
 SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE MultiIndustry__c IN ('A;B','C;D')
```

This finds records where A and B, or C and D, are selected.

Comment: Worth also noting that while the picklist value API name cannot include that semi-colon, there's nothing stopping it being added to the label for the picklist value.

Answer (score 1):

Given that semi-colon is not supported (for the reason given by sfdcfox) and all other UTF-8 are supported (AFAIK, including emojis), and if you really need a semi-colon

- Use `﹔` which is the UTF-8 character for [small semi-colon](https://graphemica.com/%EF%B9%94) or
- Use `；` which is the UTF-8 character for [full-width semi-colon](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1b/index.htm)

*Of course, this trick will no doubt lead to issues if you have logic elsewhere to look for matches on this particular picklist value as you'll be tempted to use the normal `;` in the matching comparand*